# Where are the latest ruby gems: Ruby gems equivalent of search.cpan.org/recent

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cpan

Perl has a place called "http://search.cpan.org/recent"
where people can see what are the latest modules added to CPAN.

Where can a ruby programmer go to find out "what are the latest gems added to the ruby gems index" ?

Comment: https://twitter.com/rubygems ?

Comment: If those that be think questions about gems and repositories are off topic then I would suggest their opinion is likewise off-topic. They are correct in one regard however, it did attract opinion and spam—their's.

Comment: i thought its ridiculus four people thought it fit to close my question

Answer (score 5):

CPAN is really nice. Best I could find for RubyGems:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

JSON.load(open('https://rubygems.org/api/v1/activity/latest.json')).each { |g|
  printf("%s (%s)\n  %s\n", g['name'], g['version'], g['info']) 
}; nil
```

Output:

```
flagsToggle (0.1.0)
  flagsToggle provides a declarative, layered way of enabling and disabling application functionality at run-time
threadable_comments (0.1.0)
  Create comments along with their threads on any commentable object. Use Ancestry gem.
puree (0.6.0)
  Consumes the Pure Research Information System API and facilitates post-processing of metadata into simple data structures.
inputs (0.1.0)
  Stupid pointless gem for lazy Ruby developer to implement console interfaces for input fields like y/n questions, names, ...
...
```

RubuGems API docs:
http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-org-api/